# Can a Jew buy non-kosher food for a gentile?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, gentiles

If a Jew is entertaining non-Jews in a business setting is he allowed to buy them non-kosher food in a non-kosher restaurant?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! To correct your post, click the "edit" link above (or here: [edit]). You should also edit in what you think the concern might be, so that answers might squarely address your concerns. Note also that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends. You might also consider [registering](/users/login) your account for [access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Dairy and meat cooked together would definitely be a problem since a Jew can't derive even indirect benefit from "basar b'chalav".

Comment: @loewian How is he deriving even indirect benefit in this case?

Comment: @Daniel Gratitude is considered indirect benefit.

Answer (score 9):

from [Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/buying-non-kosher-food.html):

> The Shulchan Aruch (YD 117:1) writes that one mustn’t do business with any food which is forbidden to eat mideoraisa. The Rema and Beis Yosef (YD 117) write that one mustn’t, therefore, buy such food for one’s non-Jewish workers as one stands to benefit from giving such gifts (See Kaf Hachaim YD 117:28).
>
> The Taz (YD 117:2), however, allows buying such food for workers, as this does not constitute business (See Shach YD 117:3).

He continues to explain that this doesn't apply to everything, as one can't for example, buy anything that is made up of meat and milk, etc:

> As meat and milk that were cooked together are assur behanaah, (forbidden to benefit from, See Shulchan Aruch YD 87:1), if one received such a food product, one may not even pass it on to a non-Jew. The Rema writes that this doesn’t apply to chicken cooked in milk (or other foods assur miderabanan). Thus, one may buy food that is bishul akum, etc.
>
> The Kaf Hachaim (YD 117:52) writes, however, that even those poskim who are stringent would allow buying gifts for non-Jews. Likewise, the Aruch Hashulchan (YD 117:19) writes that one doesn’t need to spend more money in order to buy Kosher food.